# Selecting characters immediately preceding a capturing group but separated by space in regex

Tags: python, regex

How can I select characters immediately preceding a capturing group divided by space using regex (python flavor)? For instance, if I have the string "abc alk op7212", I want to select only the "op" since it is before my capturing group of the digits.
Here is my current script:

```
(\d*)
```

It currently selects the digits only. If I add \w before it then it selects all the words before the digits. I feel like the solution is simple but I can't seem to find anyone who has asked this question before.

Comment: Please include your current Python script and also point out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this regex :

```
(\b\w+?)(?=\d)
```

in python

```
import re 
s = "abc alk op7212"
print(re.search(r"(\b\w+?)(?=\d)",s).group(1))
```

output

```
op
```

[**this is one match example**](https://onlinegdb.com/ryBuHB7Yw) 
[**this is multiple match example**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1e_LS7Kv)

Answer (score 0):

Capture in group 1 word characters without a digit, followed by matching a digit.

```
\b([^\W\d]+)\d
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AQ4evj/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DznxEe)

```
import re

s="abc alk op7212"
print(re.search(r"\b([^\W\d]+)\d", s).group(1))
```

Output

```
op
```